# Open all iCloud tabs from iPhone on Mac

Tags: iphone, mac, icloud, safari, tabs

TLDR; Is there a way to simultaneously open all iCloud tabs saved on iPhone, on a Mac?

I use my iPhone for browsing and as a means of "read it later" I just leave the open tabs there with the purpose of opening them all later on my Mac. Is there a way to open them all (much like Chrome allows in the "Tabs from other devices" in History page)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming you don't require them to open literally simultaneously, but simply rapidly, this is quite doable.

First, add the iCloud Tabs icon ([image: iCloud Tabs icon]) to your Safari toolbar, if it isn't there already. To do this, right-click the toolbar, select "Customize Toolbar…", and drag the icon to where you want it.

[image: add the icon to the toolbar]

Once the icon is in your toolbar, click it. A list of tabs open on your other devices will appear. To quickly open lots or all of these pages in Safari, simply hold down the command key (<kbd>⌘</kbd>) while you click each site you want to open.

Command-clicking a link, bookmark, or other reference to a page will, by default, open it in a background tab. If you find, when you command-click one of the items in the list, that it opens in the foreground and closes the iCloud Tabs menu, either *shift*-command-click, or deselect "When a new tab or window opens, make it active" in Safari's tab preferences (Safari > Preferences… > Tabs).

Edit: The third-party tool [CloudyTabs](https://github.com/josh-/CloudyTabs) is a menu bar application which includes the ability to open all your iCloud tabs at once. (h/t Matt Sephton for finding it!)

Comment: Even though not so easy to use as the Chrome solution and tabs opened on iPhone take some time to appear on desktop, it fits the bill. Thanks!

Comment: I wonder if this could be automated with AppleScript?

Comment: @MattSephton Good idea! I don't have the chops necessary, but if it helps there's a .db file at ~/Library/Application Support/Safari/CloudTabs.db which I assume contains the relevant data. I wasn't able to open it using my SQLite browser though...

Comment: @TimothyMueller-Harder I'll try soon because I'm currently in this situation

Comment: I used CloudyTabs to open them all on my Mac.

Comment: Also, the location of the file is actually `~/Library/Safari/CloudTabs.db`

Comment: @MattSephton Good find, I've added CloudyTabs to my answer!

Comment: @MattSephton LOL! Sorry!

Comment: No worries. Happens so often, even on my wedding day!

Comment: In macOS 12.3, the database path appears to have moved to `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Safari/Data/Library/Safari/CloudTabs.db`.

Answer (score 1):

One option that may work indirectly if you can easily locate the segment in time in which you were browsing on the other device is to use the History view, then you can select a range of tabs using <kbd>shift</kbd>+click and/or <kbd>cmd</kbd>+click, and then you can hold <kbd>cmd</kbd> and double-click to open all in tabs.